# How fast does a black hole spin?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, event-horizon, angular-velocity, kerr-metric

When a star dies it explodes in a supernova. This happens when heavier elements like iron is fused in the core of the star. Then the star collapses under its own gravity. This leaves a black hole behind. Now in order to conserve momentum the star must spin. So does a black hole spin? If so at what speed does a black hole spin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do black holes have a moment of inertia?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310881/) or [What is black hole spin?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262877)

Comment: It does spin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole

Comment: You answered your own question. Conservation of momentum must be maintained.

Comment: Note also that a supernova does not always leave being a black hole, it can (possibly more often) leave behind a neutron star.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer. Suppose Mass of the star is 10 kg and its velocity is 100 m/s initially. So initial momentum is 1000 kg m/s. Now some mass has exploded into a supernova and what remains is a dense ball of matter which is caused due to the collapse of the gravity of the star.

Now mass is say 5 kg after the supernova (Which is mass of the black hole) so velocity must be 200 m/s. So final momentum is again 1000 kg m/s. This way we can apply conservation of momentum and derive the velocity. Is this correct?

Comment: One black hole, at the heart of galaxy NGC 1365 is turning at 84% the speed of light.

Comment: That is an unrealistic mass and rotational velocity for a star.

Comment: @avito009 You are missing liniar momentum with angular momentum. To conserve angular momentum rotational speed needs to increase because as radius shrinks.