# Explain Kerr-Newmann Black Hole Spins in SI Units

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, dimensional-analysis, kerr-newman-metric

I'm trying to run some calculations on [Kerr-Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) black holes, but I'm having two major difficulties.  First, most equations I've been able to find are only for [Kerr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole) black holes.  Second, essentially all equations are in one of several incompatible varieties of "[natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)" (this is a big problem for me, since my background is not in Physics, and so I don't magically know when to multiply things by $c$, $G$, $k_B$, $\hslash$, $M$, etc.).

In approximately increasing order of my confusion:

- "$J$": I assume this is angular momentum, with the usual $\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}^2\cdot\text{s}^{-1}$ units?
- "$J_{max}(M)$": Presumably the maximum [allowable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis) value of $J$ for a given mass $M$ (in $\text{kg}$).  I found [an SI formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262877/what-is-black-hole-spin) for a Kerr black hole.  Would it be different for a Kerr-Newman black hole?
- "$\Omega$": Angular velocity (from an observer at infinity, with units $\text{rad}\cdot\text{s}^{-1}$, I assume).  I found [this formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/310900/10909) for Kerr, not Kerr-Newman, and I couldn't get the units to make sense.
- "$M$": I assume this is mass in $\text{kg}$.  But, I've also seen it rescaled to $\text{m}$, somehow.
- "$a$": Some kind of spin parameter?  Unclear how exactly this relates to $J$.  AFAICT, there are multiple definitions, with dimensionless units, meters (e.g. as $J/(M c)$ from [Abramowicz and Fragile 2013](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5499.pdf) $\S 3$), and possibly other units.  Is the dimensionless version supposed to be $a/M$, with $M$ rescaled to length (by $GM/c^2$) or something?  I also found a dimensionless version [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/262879/10909) as a ratio of $J$ to $J_{max}(M)$.  How does that tie in?
- "$a/M$": Specific angular momentum?  Seen in e.g. [Bardeen et al. 1972 (fig 1.)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1972ApJ...178..347B&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf).  Also seems [to be called $\chi$, "dimensionless spin"](https://duetosymmetry.com/tool/kerr-calculator-v2/).  Does this have anything to do with [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics))?

For each of these quantities (and anything else relevant), I'm looking for (1) their **scientific names** (so I can research them), (2) their **SI definitions** (so I can do dimensional analysis on them), and (3) their **SI equations for Kerr-Newman** black holes (so I can calculate them).  At least a self-consistent explanation of $a$, $a/M$ and how they relate to $J$, as treated in the literature, so that I'm not completely lost when reading it anymore.

Comment: May I ask what you are doing this for?  If you can't convert from natural units, understanding GR, which is much more subtle, is going to be a giant bear.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer My problem is that there are different varieties of natural units, and when coupled with the fact that sources disagree about the equations (due to errors), I can't use dimensional analysis to make an educated guess to corroborate them. Required for [this project](https://space.geometrian.com/calcs/black-hole-params.php).

Comment: In the GR community, the converstion is always taking meters to be the base unit, and using factors of $G$ and $c$  (and $k$, if there are temperatures) along with dimensional analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric the Kerr-Newman (KN) metric is given in SI units and all metric parameters are defined. $J$ is the black holes (BH) angular momentum, $Q$ its charge and $M$ its mass.

$a=J/(M c)$ is called "Kerr parameter" or angular momentum per unit mass it has the dimension of length. One can get this dimensionless by e.g.
$\chi=a/(M G)c^2$. I am not aware of an interpretation of $\chi$ as a quantum mechanical spin but I know that the a KN BHhas a Dirac gyromagnetic ratio of $\gamma_{KN}=Q a c$. For more information on that topic I would recommend the references in section "Interpretive issues" of http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kerr-Newman_metric .

The a KN BH has two horizons $r_\pm$:
$$r_\pm=\frac{M G}{c^2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{M G}{c^2}\right)^2-a^2-r_Q^2},\tag{1}$$
with $r_Q\equiv \frac{Q^2 G}{4\pi\epsilon_0 c^4}$ as the length scale corresponding to the black holes charge Q. A Kerr-Newman black hole is extremal for $r_+=r_-$ which means for $a_{ext}$
$$a_{ext}=\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{M G}{c^2}\right)^2-r_Q^2}.$$

The angular velocities on the horizons of the Kerr metric are given by

$$\Omega_\pm=\frac{a}{a^2+r_\pm}c,\tag{2}$$

so using eq. (1) would lead to a charge contribution. Which makes sense, since the KN metric has electromagnetically induced frame-dragging but I am not certain if (2) is correct for a KN BH.

Maybe after that one short note on geometrical units in General relativity $GR$: they usually use only $G=c=1$ and use that to convert all dimensions to powers of length: a second can be converted to a meter by multiplying with $c$ and a kilogram  can be converted to meter by multiplying it with $G/c^2$. For currents or charges there are a few conventions out there. One example would be $\mu_0/(4\pi)=c=G=1$ which makes currents dimension less. One Ampere can be converted multiplying it with $\sqrt{G \mu_0/(4\pi)}/c^2$.  If temperatures are involved $k_B=1$ can be used to convert temperatures into energies. Energies can be converted to length by multiplying with $G/c^4$. $\hbar$ is not common in GR since $c=G=\hbar=k_B=\mu_0=1$ would result in completely dimensionless Planck units. But in principle $\hbar$ can be used instead of $G$ to convert masses or with $c=G=k_B=\mu_0=1$ to eliminate the last dimension.

Geometrized units are not hard to understand and extremely useful in theoretical physics, since they make equations less cluttered and numerical computations easier.

Comment: I am still properly processing this answer. But for now, shouldn't it be $(M G / c^2)^2$ in the radicals?

Comment: Yes. I was to focused about adding the right constants and forgot those squares. I have corrected it in the answers.

Comment: Thought so. Anyway, this answer is really great; thanks! Re: $\Omega_{\pm}$, the formula for the surface area of the outer horizon, $A_H=4\pi(r_+^2+a^2)$, is similar in form, and is correct for Kerr-Newman.

Comment: I think it should be "$r_Q^2 \equiv$", also.

Comment: . . . and $r_\pm^2$ in the calculation of $\Omega_\pm$.

Answer (score 1):

To get the dimensionless spin parameter use

$$\rm \bar a=\frac{J c}{G M^2}$$

where J is the angular momentum of the black hole (the angular momentum J can be expressed in terms of GM²/c, so divide by that to get rid of the dimensions). This always gives a number between 0 and 1 for black holes (regular objects also can have spin parameters [larger than 1](http://3dhouse.se/ingemar/exjobb/The%20Angular%20Momentum%20of%20Kerr%20Black%20Holes.pdf#page=11), but those have to eject some of their angular momentum before collapsing to a black hole). If for some reasons you want to keep the M in the equations instead of setting G=M=c=K=1, just divide by M instead of M².