# What spins as a black hole? (lame question)

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, kerr-metric, frame-dragging

Obviously I am not a physicist.

I have seen [What is black hole spin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262877)
but this is not what puzzles me.

If I understand correctly, black hole has only three features (please correct me):

- angular momentum, i.e. spin.
- charge
- mass

My problem is to understand what spins.
The matter that might spin is disconnected from Schwarzschild radius due to limit of the light speed.

Schwarzschild radius in another hand, is the mathematical concept, it doesn't spin, does it?

So please could you explain WHAT spins exactly?

**EDIT**: I see that my question was corrected so "*angular momentum, i.e*" is added but angular momentum of what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503799/

Comment: @gs possibly but "The curvature singularity in the center of the space-time is a ring" the ring of what? I am more stupid than you expect.

Comment: A ring *of curvature singularity*.  By "is a ring", Void means "is ring-shaped".

Comment: *sigh* You can see influence of whatever is inside of black hole via its angular momentum just like with gravity or charge. Spacetime itself doesn't care about event horizon - in fact black hole even drags surrounding spacetime with itself while rotating.

Comment: " in fact black hole even drags surrounding spacetime with itself while rotating." i think this is a key point. the spacetime around the event horizon is what is spinning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents of the euro.

Lets take a specific observation of black holes the LIGO merger,[seen here](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/video/ligo20160211v3) .

The video is a complicated solution from the data gathered with the experiment, but rotation is detected. It is an animation using the data.

What is rotating? The background stars to the event are distorted through the distorted space-time and thus the motion of the two black holes can be detected/calculated.

A spinning black hole will be changing the spacetime about it and it is the distortions in the background that show it off. If it is at rest with the background stars there would be no motion of the images. From conservation of angular momentum, it must be the rotating black hole that is creating the rotary motion of the images, so the black hole is assigned a spin.

> but angular momentum of what?

At the level of general relativity, where the singularity is modeled as a point it is useless to model a spinning superheavy point. If/when gravity is quantized the singularity will disappear and become a fuzzy region as the one imagined for the [beginning of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg), where all the mass will be in a volume defined by a probability space-time region, where a spin with respect with the background starts can be assigned/measured.

Comment: 1) calling that SXS simulation, a simulation “based on LIGO data” is pretty disingenuous (LIGO PR’s fault). It is a simulation with the same orbital configuration as inferred from a LIGO observation.

Comment: 2) A rotating black hole does not cause a rotating distortion of the background ( as can be easily inferred from the fact that the Kerr metric is stationary).

Comment: 3) The singularity in the Kerr metric is not modeled as a point in GR.

Comment: @mmeent  The Kerr metric "The Kerr metric or Kerr geometry describes the geometry of empty spacetime around a rotating uncharged axially-symmetric black hole with a quasispherical event horizon" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric cannot exclude the case where the universe is not an empty . And it is not necessary to use exclusively the Kerr metric. As for LIGO, I trust that it has been looked over and the mathematics is solid. I just used the video link for simplicity.

Comment: The minute perturbations caused by the universe not being empty, are (in most cases) totally insignificant and in no case would cause any movement of the background stars. This is an effect that you have made up without any basis in theory or observation.

Comment: @mmeent But it is not a movement of the background stars. It is gravitational lensing!!  due to the change is space time around the black hole https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens

Comment: Yes, and a rotating black hole will not lead to any movement of the lensed images. If you look at the lensing caused by a rotating black hole this will not change with time.

Comment: @mmeent this says differently (Kip Thorn is a known astrophysicist)https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/32/6/065001/pdf

Comment: That paper says no such thing. (Note that that paper is mostly concerned with generating the image for a camera moving relative to the black hole.)

Comment: @mmeent  what about this proposed measurement of a spinning black hole https://www.nature.com/articles/news.2011.90 https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1907

Comment: That paper also discusses a static effect on the polarization of light passing by a rotating black hole. This effect again does not depend on time. When looking at the same image of the same source at different times, the polarization will be rotated by the same amount.

Comment: from second link "These rotating massive astrophysical objects drag and intermix their surrounding space and time, deflecting and phase-modifying light emitted near them. We have found that this leads to a new relativistic effect that imprints orbital angular momentum on such light. "  ... "If the source of the gravitational field also rotates, it drags spacetime with it, causing linearly polarized electromagnetic radiation to undergo polarization rotation similar to the Faraday rotation of light in a magnetized medium. This is known as the gravitational Faraday effect"

Comment: None of that says what you (seem to) think it does. Importantly, light from the same point of origin, following the same path, will always be dragged by the same amount, leading to a purely static effect.